# How to get access to next object on demand in list in django template?

Tags: django-templates

It's newbie question, I think.

I want to iterate above two lists: first in for loop and second when some condition is true. 
How do it in django template ?

Comment: Your question isn't clear.  You have two lists and you want to do what in your template?  Maybe you can add example output to your question.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to do simple calendar.

Legend:
Events - lists with Event objects
month - calendar.Calendar().monthdatescalendar() lists with object timedate.date from  python library

```
{% for week in month %}
    {% for day in week %}
         {% if day < Events.0.startdate.date %}
              print something like <a href = "{{ Events.0.get_absolute_url }}">{{ day }} </a>
              increase Events

         {% else %}
              {{ day }}
         {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
 {% endfor %}
```